# javascript -removal of "alert" causes the remaining code not to execute

Tags: javascript, alert

I placed an alert in my javascript code to use for debugging purposes. Now that the code works I would like to remove the alert. I am able to remove all other alerts without a problem, but when I try to remove this particular alert the rest of the code that follows fails to execute. What is causing this to happen?

see excerpt of code:

```
var points = [];
alert("declare array");
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
// Calculate the points
// Work around 360 points on circle
for (var i = 0; i < 360; i++) {
    var theta = Math.PI * (i / 16);
    // Calculate next X point 
    circleY = longitude + (cLng * Math.cos(theta));
    // Calculate next Y point 
    circleX = latitude + (cLat * Math.sin(theta));
    // Add point to array 
    var aPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(circleX, circleY);
    points.push(aPoint);
    bounds.extend(aPoint);
}
points.push(points[0]); //to complete circle
var ne = bounds.getNorthEast(); //northeast boundary of rectangular bounds
var sw = bounds.getSouthWest(); //southwest boundary of rectangular bounds
for (var i = 0; i < statesobj.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < statesobj[i].values.length; j++) {
        if (bounds.contains(statesobj[i].values[j])) {
            var latChange = ((ne.lat() - sw.lat()) / 100);
            var pt2 = new google.maps.LatLng(sw.lat() - latChange, statesobj[i].values[j].lng());
            var intersections = 0;
            for (var l = 1; l < points.length; l++) {
                var seg1 = points[l - 1];
                var seg2 = points[l];
                var latdiff1 = seg2.lat() - seg1.lat();
                var latdiff2 = pt2.lat() - statesobj[i].values[j].lat();
                var londiff1 = seg2.lng() - seg1.lng();
                var londiff2 = pt2.lng() - statesobj[i].values[j].lng();
                if (londiff2 * latdiff1 - latdiff2 * londiff1 != 0) {
                    var segtest1 = (londiff1 * (statesobj[i].values[j].lat() - seg1.lat()) + latdiff1 * (seg1.lng() - statesobj[i].values[j].lng())) / (londiff2 * latdiff1 - latdiff2 * londiff1);
                    var segtest2 = (londiff2 * (seg1.lat() - statesobj[i].values[j].lat()) + latdiff2 * (statesobj[i].values[j].lng() - seg1.lng())) / (latdiff2 * londiff1 - londiff2 * latdiff1);
                    if (segtest1 >= 0 && segtest1 <= 1 && segtest2 >= 0 && segtest2 <= 1) {
                        intersections++;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (intersections % 2 == 1) {
                alert("circle contains: " + statesobj[i].name);
                break; // once find one point of state within a circle don't need to test the rest
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it fail as in compilation error or does it produces a bug?

Comment: This is your *actual* code? You're going to need to post more. I'd guess that `google.maps` is being loaded asynchronously or something.

Comment: What do you mean by "fails to execute"?  What happens?  Are they any errors?  If I remember correctly, alerts stop execution of code until they are closed.  Maybe that pause in execution was needed for some reason?  Maybe because of an asynchronous call or something.

Comment: Only thing I can come up with is that it takes time, so maybe an ajax-request can return in time. But it shouldn't have any other side-effects.

Comment: @Emil firefox says that there are no javascript errors

Comment: I think we're going to need to see a little bit more of the code in order to give you an answer

Comment: @patrick dw I posted the rest of the code

Comment: Maybe you should add some alerts to pinpoint how far in the execution the program comes? Noone is eager to read the code and execute it in the head bro :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that an alert does is that it creates a delay beacuse you have to click the frikkin' button. If the code after the alert got dependency on a completed ajax call, the ajax might be done in time beacuse the code was delayed by the alert, amirite?

```
ajax call (taking 200ms)

alert (takes 1000ms to click)

some more code exepecting ajax to be complete
```

This scenario will fail if there is no alert